# Time Machine Backup Failure | .../UBF8T346G9.Office/.../Outlook 15 Profiles/.../HxStore.hxd could not be backed up

Tags: backup, time-machine, ms-office, monterey

Time Machine continues to fail with the following message:

[image]

I'm running:

- macOS Monterey v12.4
- Outlook for Mac v16.61

Comment: 1st question: is Outlook running when this error occurs? If so, quit and try a backup.  I don't run any Micro$oft on my Mac, but maybe there's a Microsoft daemon process or six running in the background. Open Activity Monitor, and in the Search field in the upper right, type Micro and see if there are any daemons started. maybe even a daemon with 'Outlook" in its name. Select it and try Quitting or Force Quitting using the X icon in the upper left and watch to see if it stays killed. Lastly, see if there's any way in Preferences to keep MS from creating any startup items.

Comment: Thanks, this didn't show me anything but it did lead me down the path that lead to fixing my problem (for now at least).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how *correct* this is, but I tried just deleting the file (I'm not sure what it even is) and running the backup again with Outlook closed. The backup completed successfully.

I launched Outlook to make sure it didn't break something and I don't notice any issues so far. I'm not sure how often I'll have to delete this file but hopefully this helps someone in the future.

This group container stores no data that doesn’t sync down from Microsoft mail servers, so as long as there’s no mail or local rules you can safely remove this profile when it gets locked or corrupt. Making a new profile is routine troubleshooting for macOS version if Outlook.

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-profiles-or-identities-in-outlook-for-mac-fed2a955-74df-4a24-bef6-78a426958c4c

Comment: At worst, you lose any unsaved data - deleting that profile is valid when it gets locked or corrupt. I’ll edit this with official KB from MS. You might even be able to fix this by making a new profile, let it sync then reboot. If you don’t need to back this up, consider excluding it from Time Machine.